# How to run workflow or do something when a related entity is being added?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have added many-to-many relationship between (for example) Contacts and Accounts entity.
When Accounts entity is attached do Contacts (or vice versa) I would like to create another entity automatically (let's call it ContactToAccountEntity).

How can I do that? I thought about custom workflow but I did not find any way to run the workflow when related entity is added to primary entity.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to fire a plugin on the `Associate` message and then inside the plugin code you can execute your `On Demand` workflow.

Rajeev has blogged about writing a Associate plugin, take a look at it here, [Associate Dissociate Plugin](http://rajeevpentyala.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/associatedisassociate-plugin-messages-in-crm/)

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a complete example that utilizes the associate message](http://www.procentrix.com/Community/BrendenS/post.aspx?ID=25). It’s close to what you’ll need to implement in your plug-in. 
It’s only missing the few lines of code that actually create the your contactToAccountEntity.

I wouldn’t use an on demand workflow since you’ll probably want to save both account and contact lookups as reference and
a workflow only accepts a single EntityId as its target record so I don’t think it a good choice.

Also, a plug-in allows you to be both asynchronous and synchronous depending on your end goal